# Google spreadsheet color top values in a row

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've the following google spreadsheet:

[Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bftnfjCF7De5-oWZtn1srWiVdzLwuZ1ikRFBWEwqZkw/edit?usp=sharing)

I'd want to color the cells with the top five values for each row. I've tried with `conditional formatting` but I can't get the correct formula for doing it. Is there anyway to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following conditional formatting, applied to range `D2:J13`:

`=D2>=LARGE($D2:$J2;5)`

This will not break ties, including when 0 is among the "top five" values. You can ignore 0s by using:

`=D2*(D2>=LARGE($D2:$J2;5))`